# What, if any, are the disadvantages to using an object as an array index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I hadn't read that this was possible but, on a hunch, I tested whether it was possible to use an object as an index in an associative array. Like this:

```
var obj = Object(),
arr = Array();

arr[ obj ] = "things";

console.log( arr[obj] );
```

Which logs "things" to the console. This seems like a surprising amount of flexibility to me and I'd like to use it to save information about a node.

However something about it feels a little "off" as if it's too flexible. Are there any inefficiencies or caveats with using this that I should be aware of?

Comment: The main disadvantages is probably that it's  invalid, arrays have numbered indexes. Then again, there are no associative arrays?

Comment: btw. there is no advantage, because you could put the information directly in the object

Comment: don't confuse arrays (indexed by number) with what's basically only called an associative array in perl (called an object in javascript, but more universally a hash or dict).  this only works at all because you're free to add whatever keys you want to any object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object will get stringified when it is used as a property name - all object properties are strings! This means that it looses its identity as well, not being a unique identifier.

```
var obj = {};
var key = {};
obj[key] = "things"; // create a property with the name String(key)
obj["[object Object]"] // "things"
```

Notice that you [shouldn't use arrays for non-numeric keys](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/).

Comment: @RobG: Is it? AFAIR, it mentions all the important points. Do you know a better one? Or is there a canonical SO question about this? I'd be happy to improve my link list.

Comment: I just don't think it's very well written (e.g. "*I’m not trying to ridicule or scold. This misconception is too common to attribute it to stupidity*" and "*There is no way to specify string keys in an array constructor*", which is true for the Object constructor too, so irrelevant, and so on). A subset of Kangax's [*How ECMAScript 5 still does not allow to subclass array*](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/#special_nature_of_arrays) would suit better.

Comment: Yeah, it has a few flaws, but I couldn't find/write a better one yet. That section from Kangax' article is valuable information, but doesn't target "you're doing it wrong" or clears up the wrongful term "associative array".

Answer (score 2):

It isn't doing what you think:

```
> obj.toString()
"[object Object]"
> arr["[object Object]"]
"things"
```

Anything you add this way will fix into the same hard-coded key name.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want with a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), from ES6.  It's not available everywhere yet, but there are [polyfills](https://github.com/WebReflection/es6-collections).